# Dart sass errors on ID starting with number

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I have this ID from a microsoft reporting page I have to override. It never gave me any issues until I changed my gulp-sass package to gulp-dart-sass.

I have no control over the generated ID's.
`#1_ReportViewerN2_ctl09_ctl00_CurrentPage`

Is there a way around it?

https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/b61f6646765870a79017170f0ff7c302?token=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&scope=gist,read:user

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work okay.

```
[id="1_ReportViewerN2_ctl09_ctl00_CurrentPage"]
```